# AngularJs Bind Collections in form submit

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 tables: (1) Meal (2) Vegatable. Basically in form submit the user chooses 2 vegatables to add to a newly created meal.

**I. Model creation on server side:**

```
 public class Meal{

    public Meal(
       Vegatables = new List<Vegatable>();
    }

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Vegatable> Vegatables {get; set;}
}

 public class Vegatable{

    public Vegatable(
       Meals = new List<Meal>();
    }

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Meal> Meals {get; set;}
}
```

**II Form:**

```
   <div ng-controller="MealCtrl>
   <input  type="text" ng-model="meal"></select>

   <label>Choose Vegatable 1</label>
   <div ng-controller="VegatableCtrl>
   <select id="vegatable1" ng-model="vegatable" ng-options="vegatable.Name for vegatable in vegatables"></select>
   </div>      

   <label>Choose Vegatable 2</label>
   <div ng-controller="VegatableCtrl>
   <select id="vegatable2" ng-model="vegatable" ng-options="vegatable.Name for vegatable in vegatables"></select>
   </div> 

  </div>
```

**III. Question:**

Obviously, when I look at my server controller's POST method in locals window, there are no values assigned to the vegatable collection of the class Meal.

**Any ideas as to how to add the vegtables to $scope.meal before saving to the server?**

**Final Note:**

Since this is a many-to-many relationship, there will be a join table. How does that play into the POST method?

**SOLVED - As usual: BLESH to the rescue!!**

**One thing I see I had done wrong was use the VegatableCtrl in the select. I now see that a populated instance of $scope.Vegatables should be in the MealCtrl and use the MealCtrl to populate the Vegatables' select choices.**

Thanks Blesh !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like maybe your building up your object to submit incorrectly. [Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0VHjO4kmmla0aalNXd7?p=preview) showing the building of an object that your MVC method should accept.

And here's the HTML:

```html
<form ng-controller="MealCtrl" name="MealForm" ng-submit="submitMeal()">
  <select ng-model="selectedMeal" ng-options="meal.Name for meal in Meals"></select><br/>

  <label>Choose Vegatable 1
  <select ng-model="selectedVeggie1" ng-options="vegetable.Name for vegetable in vegetables"></select></label>
  <br/>

  <label>Choose Vegatable 2
  <select ng-model="selectedVeggie2" ng-options="vegetable.Name for vegetable in vegetables"></select></label>
  <br/>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the sample Angular controller:

```js
app.controller('MealCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Meals = [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'Meal 1' },
    { Id: 2,  Name: 'Meal 2' },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'Meal 3' }
  ];

  $scope.vegetables = [
    {Id: 100, Name: 'Broccoli' },
    {Id: 101, Name: 'Zucchini' },
    {Id: 102, Name: 'Green Beans' },
    {Id: 103, Name: 'Brussel Sprouts'}
  ];

  $scope.submitMeal = function (){
    //build the meal
    var meal = angular.copy($scope.selectedMeal);
    meal.Vegetables = [
      angular.copy($scope.selectedVeggie1),
      angular.copy($scope.selectedVeggie2)
      ];
    console.log(meal);
    //TODO: submit via ajax.
  }
});
```